# Doctrine INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE wait for slaves to replicate

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have an odd problem with my Symfony Doctrine Master/Slave connection. We use Amazon RDS Aurora, MySQL with Master replica. It works great, except, our app works too quickly.

Every INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE request always goes to master, then AWS RDS automatically replicates the data onto Slaves with a lag averaged at 20ms.

When our app does any of those queries and then redirects the user back at what he was doing, the app does SELECT to see the changes, and very often it's so quick that it didn't replicate yet, so the user sees the outdated information.

I would like to implement a quick fix, by adding a preferably an event listener on every request, so if Doctrine has done any INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE, I can add a sleep mechanism for additional 50-100ms so that those requests take slightly longer before returning 200 to the client so he can update.

Has anyone had a similar problem?

I guess it's a good problem to have, but very annoying and UX is dramatically reduced due to the quickness.

Please let me know if there is a better *quick* solution to this problem. Our app does many many times more reads than writes, so adding additional 100ms to write requests will not be noticed by the client. I would like to solve this at a request level. Going through each controller that does write is not an option as it's a massive application.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the in-built life-cycle hooks (https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/lifecycle_callbacks.html)

For example, using postUpdate and PHP's usleep() could help fixing your problem.

```
/**
 * @ORM\PostUpdate
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function awaitReplication() : void
{
    usleep(200);
}
```

Comment: dont forget `postPersist` as well

Comment: Of course, postPersist would be better as it would trigfer INSERT as well.